# Adding a custom validator

Tags: laravel-4

I am trying to use this [gist](https://gist.github.com/elena-kolevska/8580401#comment-1212554), which adds a custom rule to validate alphabet that allows spaces.

In my project I added a new folder which is autoload using PSR-0 to contain any additional files such as helpers, repositories.

```
"psr-0": {
    "MW": "app/"
}
```

I have namespaced them according to the folder structure

**app/mw/CustomValidatorServiceProvider.php**

```
<?php namespace MW;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Validators\CustomValidator;

class CustomValidatorServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {
    public function register(){}

    public function boot()
    {
        $this->app->validator->resolver(function($translator, $data, $rules, $messages)
        {
            return new CustomValidator($translator, $data, $rules, $messages);
        });
    }

}
```

**app/mw/Validation/CustomValidator.php**

```
<?php namespace MW\Validation;

use Illuminate\Validation\Validator;

class CustomValidator extends Validator {

    public function validateAlphaSpaces($attribute, $value, $params)
    {
        return preg_match('/^[\pL\s]+$/u', $value);
    }
}
```

I have also registered it in `app.php`

```
'providers' => array(
    'MW\CustomValidatorServiceProvider'
);
```

I have also done `composer dump-autoload -o`

My Question is why when I try to use it in my rules

`'first_name'=> 'required|alpha_spaces|min:2'`

and validate it I get the following error

> /var/www/mw/app/MW/CustomValidatorServiceProvider.php
>
> Class 'Validators\CustomValidator' not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're importing `CustomValidators` from within the `Validators` namespace and not the `MW\Validators` namespace.

It should look like this:

```
use MW\Validators\CustomValidator;
```